# CASE WHEN on Google Data Studio

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, looker-studio

Im trying to create a field on data studio that uses a "case when" and the function Date_diff. 
I keep getting the error "Could not parse formula".

1. do I need to specify the metric of the difference between the two dates (as I do on BigQuery)?
2. can I name the values with numbers, instead of strings (as possible to do on BigQuery)?
3. Do I need to cast all fields to date format, or does Data Studio recognize them as dates by its own?
4. Can I use the function "Between"?

My latest version (which isn't working) is the following:

```
case when date_diff(cast(checkin as date),order_date,day)>=0 and <=3 then 3

when date_diff(cast(checkin as date),order_date,day)>=4 and <=7 then 7

when date_diff(cast(checkin as date),order_date,day)>=8 and <=14 then 14

when date_diff(cast(checkin as date),order_date,day)>=15 and <=30 then 30

when date_diff(cast(checkin as date),order_date,day)>=31 and <=60 then 60

when date_diff(cast(checkin as date),order_date,day)>=61 and <=180 then 180

when date_diff(cast(checkin as date),order_date,day)>=181 and <=365 then 365

end
```

Comment: `sql-server` <> `mysql`. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: You case expression is not correct, it should be like case when date_diff(cast(checkin as date),order_date,day)>=0 and date_diff(cast(checkin as date),order_date,day) <=3 then 3 or you can also use between

Comment: @Larnu using BigQuery - Standard SQL (does it answer it?), sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @PSK thanks, just noticed it. I tried the way you wrote, and it still isn't working.

Comment: @TomS sometimes I encounter the issue that when I edit an already saved field, I'll keep getting parsing error. But if I copy & paste the code into a new field, it'll save fine. You might want to give that a try to eliminate the fact that it's something wrong with your code.

Comment: @vinoaj I actually did the opposite, and used an existing field that was created using the function "Date_diff", and then it worked.. and now, after creating the filed, I cant use this field in any table :( It shows a Configuration Error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your condition:

```
(case when date_diff(cast(checkin as date), order_date, day) >= 0 and <= 3 then 3
 . . .
```

This doesn't make sense.  You can express this as

```
(case when date_diff(cast(checkin as date), order_date, day) between 0 and 3 then 3
```

I would be more inclined to write this as:

```
(case when checkin >= order_date and checkin < date_add(order_date, interval 4 day)
```

You might need various casts to make this work, depending on the types of the underlying columns.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up defining two new fields - thats the only way I was able to create what I wanted. I created one that specifies the date diff. e.g one field was defined by date_diff(checkin,order_date), and the second used the 1st one, instead of using the date_diff function inside a case..  and then it worked.  any idea why it didnt let me use the function inside a case?